# Using argv to change directory upon running python file

Tags: python, argv

I currently have a python file that, along with an external parameter, will analyze data when run inside of timestamped folders (e.g. I move `readA3200dat.py` and `ParameterFile.ini` into a folder named 201806151534, etc.). However I want to use `argv` to eliminate the need to constantly move these files in and out of folders.

Because my code is pretty long, I was hoping to be able to write a function called `main` that would basically move into `<FILENAME>` upon entering `python readA3200dat.py <FILENAME>` to the command line and execute the code as usual.

Also, since I require the parameter folder, `ParameterFile.ini` to be in the same directory, I was hoping for this to be moved, but since it is always the same name, I don't need `argv`.

This is my code (cut down a bit):
**Note: the code is only relevant to show general coding structure - I am including it strictly because I am unsure where in the code I am supposed to include the `argv` syntax.**

```
import os
import numpy as np
import re

class DataStructure(object):  #Data File Class

    '''Object to contain data file information parsed in readA3200dat'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.AxisName = None
        ## more like this ##

def readA3200dat(filename): 
    ''' 
    Takes in the file path of dat file
    Returns Data structure with information from dat file
    '''
    if filename == None: # if filename is None, return None
        print("\nWARNING: Filename set to None, returning None")
        return None, None

    try: # try to open file
        f = open(filename, 'r')  #open the specified file

    except IOError as e:
        print ("\nI/O error({0}): {1}\n".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
        raise

    fileLine = f.readline() #read data in to fileLine list


### Data Reading and Analysis ##

cur_dir = os.getcwd()
folders = os.listdir(cur_dir)

for i in folders:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(i)
    if ext == '.dat':
        data = readA3200dat(i)
        ## find average values, std, etc. ##
try:
    from configparser import ConfigParser
except ImportError:
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('ParameterFile.ini')

# read values from a section
GainAff = config.getfloat('Section 1', 'gainaff')
## more like this ##

## print values ##

if os.path.isfile("ResultingSettleTimes.txt") == False:
    y = open("ResultingSettleTimes.txt", 'w')
    y.write('#GainAff / GainVff /  FFA  / Traj.FIR /  RampRate  / SettleTime(avg)#')
    print '\nPrinting to ResultingSettleTimes.txt'
    ## Write a bunch of stuff to the .txt file ##
```

Because I am not experienced with using the `argv` syntax, I am not sure where to add things like `sys.argv[0]`, etc.

I tried to just create a function `__main__(argv)` and tell it to change directories, then execute the rest of my code as normal, but it doesn't execute the code. Instead, it tells me:

```
avg_set = avg_set/(len(settle_data))
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I think it is because the program isn't actually changing into the timestamped folder, so it does not see the .dat files within the folder.

How would I implement `argv` be able to use this code within a different file?

Comment: `os.chdir(sys.argv[1])`? It's not entirely clear what you are asking, but I'm willing to bet at least 90% of the code you posted is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry - I included a lot of the code because I am not sure if I should be referencing `argv` within the bulk of the code, or just outside the function `readA3200dat()`. I am trying to determine how to take all of this code and run it inside whatever file I specify as `<FILENAME>` when putting `python readA3200dat.py <FILENAME>` into the command line.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "take all this code and run it inside whatever file"; you almost certainly want to have a single script outside of your data folders and simply point it at various directories. You're not _putting your code_ anywhere different.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed strategy is fine; your core problem is that you're not handling the value of `argv` correctly. If you want to go with your original plan, debug your script (see [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pdb.html)) to see the value of `argv`. Then adjust your code to grab out the parts you want, and pass those to `__main__`.

Additionally, I suggest you use [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/optparse.html) rather than `argv`. It helps you follow modern conventions for command line tools and provide documentation.